# How can I get boarding card in UK Gatwick airport with Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV)?

Tags: air-travel, transit, uk, british-airways, datv

I am from Iran and I have been issued a UK DATV (Direct Airside Transit Visa). In London Gatwick airport, I've got a connection from from Turkish airline to British Airways. But as long as there are limitations for this visa how should I get British Airways boarding card while I change my flight from Turkish airline. Unfortunately British Airways agency in Iran in closed. Is it possible to get boarding cards with DATV in London Gatwick airport or not?

Comment: BA normally offer online checkin, along with printing your boarding pass, 24 hours before departure. Could you not do this, and print your boarding pass before setting off from home?

Comment: British Airways and Turkish Airlines use different terminals at Gatwick. I confess I am not a regular Gatwick user, but is there actually an airside bus? I am not sure your DATV is valid in that circumstance.

Answer (score 5):

There are two options available to you.

One option is to take advantage of the fact that BA offer [Online Checkin](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/checking-in) and [Mobile Checkin](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/checking-in). This opens up 24 hours in advance. You head to the BA website or mobile app, type in your flight details (or BA Executive Club details, if you're a member and have associated it with your booking). You can then enter any advanced passenger information that's needed, pick your seat, and complete checkin. If checking in online, you're then given your boarding pass to print. With the mobile app, it downloads the boarding pass to your phone/tablet, and shows it on that. This option lets you sort it all out a day in advance, and as a bonus lets you pick a good seat!

Otherwise, when you land at Gatwick Airport, you'll need to follow the signs for [Flight Connections](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/Flight-Connections/). There's a lot of information on it on [the airport's website](http://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/Flight-Connections/), including an example of the bright pink signs you need to follow. That'll take you to an area where all the airlines have counters. Find the BA one there, queue up, show your passport, and they'll issue you your boarding pass. You can then clear security, and go to wait for your flight.

Speaking of flight connections, I presume from your question that you're flying Iran -> Istanbul, Istanbul -> Gatwick, Gatwick -> elsewhere. As such, you'll be going through flight connections at Istanbul when you arrive in Turkey. BA fly to Istanbul, so if the timing is right, you might even be able to get a BA agent in Istanbul to print your boarding pass there. If not, it's fine (and quite normal) to get it when you reach Gatwick.

(Because Turkish Airlines is in Star Alliance, and British Airways is OneWorld, it won't be possible for Turkish Airlines to issue you with a BA boarding pass when you check in).

Comment: Is there an airside inter-terminal bus in the FCC? It is not mentioned on the website, and I don't remember seeing one, but I am not a frequent LGW user. TK and BA use different terminals.

Comment: Gatwick is in the process of shuffling airlines between terminals, partly so that Easyjet can have all its flights in the same place. They're doing lots of building works for those changes, so I don't know what the situation is right now, but TK and BA should end up in the same terminal when it's all done...

Comment: Yes BA are changing terminals, but not until November 2016. Right now BA/TK are in separate buildings, and I have a feeling one has to go landside to change terminals.